# Isolate Seconds from Matlab Clock

Tags: matlab, clock, system-clock, benchmarking

I am trying to achieve two things:

1. Start a function if the current time is an exact 10 seconds multiple and
2. Run the function in a loop every 10 seconds after that

---

I have a cronjob on AWS pulling data every 10 seconds. I want my MATLAB function to run specifically once that has been updated (every 10 seconds).

The function takes less than 10 seconds to run. Currently, I am doing:

```
tic
function
toc
elapsedTime=toc;
pause(10-elapsedTime);
```

but this dosent seem to be working. On top of that, I want the entire function to start at 1:00:10 (seconds).

I think using Matlab's

```
format shortg
c = clock
fix(c)
```

and some how starting at sec = [0,10,20....,60] would work, but I am not sure how to isolate the seconds from the system clock.

Comment: The [`Timer` class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html) would be a much better choice for this sort of thing. And what do you specifically mean by "this dosent seem to be working"? Your `tic`/`toc` code seems fine (though it won't be super accurate and there's no need to call `toc` twice unless you want the time printed). Are you showing all of your code?

Comment: sure, the tic-toc isnt exactly precise, but I read that is unavoidable.

Comment: However, how do i go about starting the function initially at a multiple of 10 seconds in real time ... i.e. I want it to start at 1 PM, 10 Min, and 10 Seconds .....